# Xcode, Not able to detect SwipeGesture after i add Animation on my ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Before start,

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *seipeges=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftswipe:)];
    seipeges.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:seipeges];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightgesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightswipe:)];
    rightgesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightgesture];
```

this swipe detect code is run well.
after that i add animation on my UIScrollView.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     if(leftright==1)
                         [imgCell.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake((-newOffSetX), 0)];
                     else
                         [imgCell.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

the animation is run well also.
if the animation not yet start, the UISwipeGestureRecognizer is still running well.
then i found out, when the animation start, it not able to detect UISwipeGestureRecognizer any more.

so any one can tell me what i missing? or why the SwipeGesture code is not able to run after animation start?

Comment: try setting `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to the option and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i post the solution at here.

try setting UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | **UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction** to the option and see if it works.